# Routing table for multilingual web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to make a multilingual ASP.NET MVC site.
Here is how I need the URLs to look like

`www.mysite.com/home` -> must be English and call Index action of the Home controller

`www.mysite.com/test` -> must be English and call Index action of the Test controller

`www.mysite.com/es/home` -> must be Spanish and call Index action of the Home controller

`www.mysite.com/es/test` -> must be Spanish and call Index action of the Test controller

Here is how my rout table looks like. 
What I don’t like is that I need to have 2 entries for the same thing.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "controller",
            url: "{controller}",
            defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index" }                
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "multilang-controller",
            url: "{lang}/{controller}",
            defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
            constraints: new { lang = "en|es|de|fr" }
        );
```

I was thinking to have something like this only

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "controller",
            url: "{lang}\{controller}",
            defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
            constraints: new { lang = "en|es|de|fr" }
        );
```

But this is not working because when I call `www.mysite.com/test` it maps `test` to the `lang` and since it is against the constraint it throws 404.

There must be more elegant way to do this instead of having 2 records for each case.

Comment: They are two different route patterns, so I think you're going to need two different routes. I don't really see that that's "not elegant."

Comment: Well I am concerned that route table will have twice the data it needs.

Comment: The difference is negligible.

Comment: Yes Ant P, may be that's true... I was just thinking that if there is a better option ...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `QueryStringRequestCultureProvider`. In `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ...)` call

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(...);
```

passing an instance of `RequestLocalizationOptions.` In this options instance locate the existing `QueryStringRequestCultureProvider` instance and set its `QueryStringKey/UIQueryStringKey` properties to the values you need. The defaults are 'culture' and 'ui-culture'.

If you do not change the values your URL would look like this:

```
http://localhost:5000/?culture=fr-FR&ui-culture=fr-BE
```

If, however, you need a URL segment instead of query string parameter, you'll have to implement **your own OWIN middleware** to handle the scenario.

What happens "under the hood" is this: the provider inspects the request URL's query part and if it contains the parameters it sets the corresponding culture(s). This is oversimplified a bit. In fact the overridden `DetermineProviderCultureResult()` determines the requested culture(s) and returns `ProviderCultureResult` to the RequestLocalizationMiddleware. In its Invoke() method it receives the `ProviderCultureResult` and sets `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`. Then the URL is passed further and reaches the MVC.

Having this said maybe you'd feel better using most of the solutions coming out-of-the-box, and only if something is not available implementing your own.

More on the topic in here: 
http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/how-aspnet5-determines-culture-info-for-localization